# Animatronic Eye Mechanism - Eye Socket Spring Tension

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanisms, cad, machining

I am building an animatronic eye mechanism that will ultimately be moved via servo motors for a project I am working on.

It is comprised of the following components:

1. Eye Plate - 3mm thick Acrylic disk that has 3/8in eye sockets milled into it
2. Eye Screws - m2 eye bolt screws that screw into the rear of the eyeballs and mount on the draw bar
3. Draw Bar - Brass bar that constrains the movement of both eyes by mounting to both eye screw eyelets

[image]

I want to apply spring tension between the back of the acrylic 'eye plate' and the front of the brass 'draw bar'. This will effectively trap the eyeballs inside their respective milled eye sockets and not allow the entire assembly to fall forward out of the eye plate while still allowing smooth eye movement operation.

**My requirements are:**

1. Nothing can be added to the front of the eye plate to retain the eyeballs; they must remain in the sockets with no capturing plate on the front
2. The eyeballs must be able to operate and move in a ball-joint in all directions inside their respective sockets
3. Extending the length of the eyeball screws can occur but only by a few millimeters at most due to size constraints. This assembly is inside a confined bore the same diameter of the eye plate (30mm)

**What I've tried:**

I placed a m2 countersunk screw in-between the eyeball sockets that protrudes out the rear of the eye plate thinking that I would be able to place a spring over the shaft of the screw and do the same thing on the draw bar shaft as shown in the following photo. However, it became immediately obvious that the axis' of either shaft move out of alignment when the eyeball assembly moves. This would create bizarre tension on the spring and would likely lead to it popping off of the shaft.

[image]

**My Ideas:**

I feel as though the best course of action would be to have 2 springs that are mounted over the shafts of both eye screws because the axis would always be aligned there. However, due to the milled eye sockets the spring would be pressing on the back of the eyeballs which would have virtually no effect.

How can I constrain the spring between the rear of the eye plate and the draw bar while allowing proper operation?

Comment: maybe the orbs can be held magnetically

Comment: The eye ball orbs are made of delrin so thats not really an option at this point I'm afraid.